# working on multiple git features on visual studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is there a way i can work on multiple different git features (on same repository) using multiple instances of `Visual Studio 2017` running simultaneously? (like each `Visual Studio` referring to different git feature). I am using `git hub extension` for `Visual Studio`.

Comment: this kind of thing is what people use `git worktree` for. with it you can create multiple working trees that relate to the same repo. you can have a  different branch on each of the subtrees.

Comment: did I say `subtree`? ;-)

Comment: @eftshift0 definitely not :-p